# Key Card Battery Low message after replacing battery

Tags: key, renault, megane

I have a late 2012 Renault Megane and when using one of our key cards the dashboard displayed a message about the battery being low. I have replaced the battery with a brand new one and the message is still being displayed.

Is there anything I need to do to reset the warning, or does it indicate some other issue?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says in manuals: Press one of the buttons on the card four times close to the vehicle, The next time the vehicle is started, the message will disappear.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have got rid of the message! It makes me worry that it's measuring how many times you've unlocked the car, not the voltage of the battery, but at least the message has gone now!

Comment: It won't be measuring the voltage of the battery, it'll have some tolerance and raise an alert when weak voltage is detected.  One triggered, it'll continue to display the message until reset.